# How can i use custom site maintainance page in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I want to show a custom site under maintenance page. But how can i achieve this without playing with the core?

```
<?php
function phptemplate_maintenance_page($content, $messages = TRUE, $partial = FALSE) {
  $path = $base_path . $directory; 
  drupal_goto($path .'offline.html');
}

?>
```

This didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you try to use instead a custom maintenance-page.tpl.php ? http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--maintenance-page.tpl.php/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I always do, is avoiding that offline message alltogether. It is useless in most cases where one upgrades anyway, because during the upgrade there is a moment where part of the files are in place, and others are not (yet), or moments when the database goes down and so on.

Avoiding it, is pretty simple:

- Add your own `index.html`, containing a message about being offline.
- Rename `.htaccess` to something else, like `DISABLED.htaccess`, or emptying it. Make sure that during upgrade it does not accidentally re-appear.

It may be that .htaccess is not the one directing apache at index.php over index.html, as is the case on most servers. In that case, you will need to alter the vhost too, so as to make it prefer index.html *above* index.php.

Drupals .htaccess makes sure that `index.php` is preferred *above* `index.html`, so you can safely leave that file in the root directory in production. (I store it in the git repository with everything else)

Once you are done, all you need, is to put back the .htaccess and Drupal will be zooming along.

If you wish access to your site during the offline process, you can do so, by accessing http://example.com/index.php. You should also disable clean urls if you want to click trough your site while being offline. e.g. your admin settings area is at http://example.com/index.php?admin/settings.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to copy,paste the "page.tpl" file in your theme, rename the new file to "maintenance-page.tpl.php". This works in Drupal 6 and I suppose it should work in Drupal 7 too but not sure though. Its worth trying this first.